# How to rotate a QQuaternion on two axes

Tags: android, c++, qt, qglwidget

I'm working with qglwidget and various gestures for an android app and the topic of Quaternions is thoroughly confusing so its been mostly guess and check. I've been able to make a rotation about one axis by some number of degrees using:

```
rotation=QQuaternion::fromAxisAndAngle(QVector3D(1,0,0),delta.y())*rotation;
```

This has the desired results as does the same statement in the x direction.

My question is, for one, is the the correct way of doing a rotation? And two, if I want to rotate on two axes do I just do:

```
rotation=QQuaternion::fromAxisAndAngle(QVector3D(1,0,0),delta.y())*rotation;
rotation=QQuaternion::fromAxisAndAngle(QVector3D(0,1,0),delta.x())*rotation;
```

Or is there a one line statement that will work just as well?

Comment: First of all, your definition of an axis is not quite right in this problem.  Skipping all of the minor details, an axis is just a normalized vector.  Try doing `...(QVector3D(.707,.707,0),QVector3D(delta.x(),delta.y(),delta.z()))`.  I assume `delta` is some `QVector3D` that you are rotating about, and `x()`, `y()`, and `z()` are getters.  What is `rotation`?

Comment: Sorry, that is not right; I just looked up the library you are using (and actually read the function name lol).  Is `delta` a set of Euler angles?

Comment: rotation is what I pass to matrix.rotate on paint calls. matris is then used in gl as program.setUniformValue("mvp_matrix", projection * matrix). The units of delta are arbitrary coming from a touch event but given their values I assume they're in radians.

Comment: If delta is in Euler angles, then having 3 conversion lines of code (one for each basis) like in the OP is about as good as you can do.  There are ways to convert Euler angles to quaternions, but the process takes roughly the same amount of calculations and essentially does the same thing (makes quaternions out of each rotation component and compounds the whole thing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are doing it the right way, there are no one-line statement :-)

It is very common in 3D applications to create a quaternion from a set of Euler angles, and we do this simply by multiplying together the most basic rotations, since it is anyway pretty cheap to compute (unless you are doing a *lot* of them, and determined by profiling that this part was critical for performance). For instance, if you are using the convention Z-X-Z (as illustrated in the first picture [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) ), then you would write:

```
QQuaternion rotation =
    QQuaternion::fromAxisAndAngle(QVector3D(0,0,1), alpha) *
    QQuaternion::fromAxisAndAngle(QVector3D(1,0,0), beta) * 
    QQuaternion::fromAxisAndAngle(QVector3D(0,0,1), gamma);
```

where `alpha`, `beta` and `gamma` are `double` values representing the angles in degrees (be careful, not in radians).

Note: you can create the one-liner yourself by wrapping it in your own method:

```
static QQuaternion fromEuler(double alpha, double beta, double gamma);
```